# How to Send message via apacheMQ in between two servlets?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications, activemq-classic

I am trying to integrate apacheMQ in my web application running on Tomcat. I found some tutorials about local integration (I do not intend to do the global integration) but I am not sure how to proceed. All the tutorials seem to be quite confusing to a beginner.

Could you please take a look on my code and suggest if I am on a right path to implement this? My intention is to send some messages from one servlet (add it to queue) and then read these message from a queue with different servlet.

This code is based on [THIS TUTORIAL](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html).

Class for handling messages:

```
public class Messenger {

    public static void sendMessage(String msg) {
        // configure the broker
        try {
            // Create a ConnectionFactory
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                    "vm://localhost");

            // Create a Connection
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            // Create a Session
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
            Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");

            // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

            // Create a messages
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(msg);

            // Tell the producer to send the message
            System.out.println("Sent message: " + message.getText());
            producer.send(message);

            // Clean up
            session.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void readQueue() {
        try {

            // Create a ConnectionFactory
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                    "vm://localhost");

            // Create a Connection
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            // Create a Session
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
            Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");

            // Create a MessageConsumer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

            // Wait for a message
            Message message = consumer.receive(1000);

            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                String text = textMessage.getText();
                System.out.println("Received: " + text);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Received: " + message);
            }

            consumer.close();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

At the moment, it is enough for me to print everything in console since this example is only for testing and debugging purposes.

Sending and receiving servlets:

```
public class SendMessageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        Messenger.sendMessage("Test message");


    }

}

public class ReadQueueServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        Messenger.readQueue();

    }

}
```

The result of accessing the ReadQueueServlet is just "Received: null".

I am not sure if I should create a context.xml for my web application in this scenario but I tried that as well. I placed the following in `WEB-INF/META-INF/context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource auth="Container"
          name="jms/ConnectionFactory"
          type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
          description="JMS Connection Factory"
          factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
          brokerURL="vm://localhost?brokerConfig=xbean:activemq.xml"
          brokerName="MyActiveMQBroker"/>

<Resource auth="Container"
          name="jms/FooQueue"
          type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
          description="JMS queue"
          factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
          physicalName="FOO.QUEUE"/>
</Context>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: instead of using vm://localhost, please use "failover://tcp://localhost:61616", I suppose as you are not mentioning the port number, connection is not successful

Comment: Shoud I change this only in the code or in the context.xml as well? Should I even be using the context?

Comment: where ever you are using vm://localhost, please it with "failover://tcp://localhost:61616", because port is a must

Comment: I changed that but now the servlet stays forever in "Waiting for localhost"

Comment: is your MQ server up, can you try to access localhost:61616 from your browser

Comment: Interesting - this webpage is not available so the MQ server is not even running, apparently :/

Comment: Try `http://localhost:8161/admin` to access web console of active mq.

Comment: Smajl, start you MQ server and then execute your code, am sure, it would work

Comment: Also not available. It is clear that the mqueue is not configured properly. I have no idea why

Comment: Do I have to start the mqeue server separately? I though that adding the context.xml to the webapp will start it automatically with the start of Tomcat, right?

Comment: No go to bin directory of active mq installation and execute `activemq` from command line.

Comment: Hoping you have downloaded Active MQ :). If not download it from [here](http://activemq.apache.org/download.html)

Comment: I have added the MQ dependency to pom.xml of my application. Is that enought?

Comment: That will just download the Active MQ API jar files needed. You have to start the server on your own.

Comment: Ok, server is running (though I got binding exception when running run.sh) but I can access the console. Still no success sending the messages though...

Comment: I am not sure if the server is runnign correctly: it prints this: http://pastebin.com/ZN86bcxK quite often

Answer (score 0):

> The result of accessing the ReadQueueServlet is just "Received: null".

This is because there no message in the queue.

```
        // Wait for a message
        Message message = consumer.receive(1000);

        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            String text = textMessage.getText();
            System.out.println("Received: " + text);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Received: " + message);
        }
```

If you see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive%28long%29) of receive method

> Returns:
>       the next message produced for this message consumer, or null if the timeout expires or this message consumer is concurrently closed

So after time expires you get null. Your code enters else block and prints message which is null.

Comment: This is what I realized... my question is why the messages are not sent and how to implement it correctly.

Comment: Code looks correct to me at first glance. Active MQ provides a web portal to see queues and it's content.  Stop your consumer. Just run the producer and see the queue content.